# Passing json array from angularJS to PHP to json file -> malformed json

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

at start, I come with a JSON array, like this one :

```
[
    {
        "login":"Admin",
        "admin":true,
        "root":true
    },
    {
        "login":"PMO",
        "admin":true,
        "root":false
    }
]
```

I want to overwrite the content of this JSON array by another, which is into the variable $scope.users
I first send it to a PHP file from a controller :

```
$http.post('php/users/deleteUser.php', $scope.users);
```

which overwrites the old json file

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    file_put_contents('../users/users.json', $data);
?>
```

But when I open the file users.json, the content is malformed :

```
0%5Blogin%5D=Admin&0%5Badmin%5D=true&0%5Broot%5D=true&0%5B%24%24hashKey%5D=01R&1%5Blogin%5D=PMO.....
```

I don't manage to get where it comes from. I've tried all possible combinations with JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, json_encode, json_decode.
I also tried to write the $http request like this :

```
$http({
    method:"POST",
    url:'php/users/deleteUser.php',
    data:$scope.users,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

But nothing changes the result.
Any idea ?

Comment: `php://input` is RAW input. You'd have to urldecode() it first to conver the `[]{}"` back to normal characters. Normally you should let PHP do it for you, which means sending over `data=$json_string` and the getting the decoded string from `$_POST['data']`

Comment: Ah thanks ! it's much better now !
however, the output is now like that in the json file : 0[login]=Admin&0... which is the json notation in php. I've tried with json_encode and json_decode, it doesn't looks like to change anything

Comment: that's not json. it's just a string of some sort. if it was json, it'd be more like `{"login":"Admin",....}`

Comment: It is $scope.users is a json array. If I replace it by {"login":"Admin",....}, the output still sends me : login=Admin&admin=true&root=true